# When did physical Death come to the world?

Tags: death

Death is certain. It comes to everybody except to those stated in the bible. But where and when did Death come to the world. Is it a natural phenomenon or something like a curse?

Comment: According to whom? There are a minority (historically speaking) of Christians who say physical death entered the world when Adam and Eve first sinned. Others say death has always existed, and this is when spiritual death entered the world. Your question needs to be made much more narrow to be answerable.

Answer (score 5):

The Bible teaches that death entered into the world because of Adam's sin:

> Therefore, just as sin entered the world through one man, and death through sin, and in this way death came to all people, because all sinned— To be sure, sin was in the world before the law was given, but sin is not charged against anyone’s account where there is no law. Nevertheless, death reigned from the time of Adam to the time of Moses, even over those who did not sin by breaking a command, as did Adam, who is a pattern of the one to come. (Romans 5:12-14)
>
> For since death came through a man, the resurrection of the dead comes also through a man. For as in Adam all die, so in Christ all will be made alive. (1 Corinthians 15:21-22)

There are debates over what type of death was involved in the fall. I believe that it was holistic death. It clearly involved spiritual death, as Adam was a sinner needing redemption. But earlier in 1 Corinthians 15 Paul says that if the resurrection we are hoping for isn't physical then our hope is in vain:

> For if the dead are not raised, then Christ has not been raised either. And if Christ has not been raised, your faith is futile; you are still in your sins. Then those also who have fallen asleep in Christ are lost. If only for this life we have hope in Christ, we are of all people most to be pitied. (1 Corinthians 15:16-19)

The solution matches the problem, and so if it required the Son of God to be resurrected to give us life, then I believe that physical death is a result of sin too.

Is death natural or a curse? There's a very real sense in which it is natural. So I would say that death's *naturalness* is a curse. The curse changed the world from a world where death was unnatural to one where it is the most natural thing of all.

Comment: I am a little confused by your answer. Do you mean death for humans only, or for animals as well? (Very small animals do not die at all so maybe they were without sin.) If you only mean humans, what do you mean by a human? Would you consider Homo Erectus a human for example? You cannot say 'the Bible teaches' as a general statement. I understand Paul to mean something completely different to you - something that actually makes sense. Maybe you can change, your opening sentence to say that to people that believe the Bible the way you do, it teaches such and such.

Comment: I believe that animal (but not insect) death is also from Adam, but that the Bible is only explicit about human death. I believe human includes H erectus. If you have a different interpretation make an answer, I would be interested to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pious opinion, fairly commonly held based of Romans 5:12 ("Sin came into the world through one man...") and Romans 6:23 ("The wages of sin is death...") that there was no death sin in the world until Adam committed the first sin. However, this ignores two facts: first, neither the condemnations pronounced by God against Adam (Genesis 3:17-19), or Eve (Genesis 3:16) mention either taking away physical immortality; second, in Genesis 3:22, the reason given for expelling Adam and Eve from the Garden of Eden is "lest he put forth his hand and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live forever."  If Adam were immortal to begin with, then the immortality would have had to have been taken away, and "lest he put forth..." would have been unnecessary.

Further, some of the smallest aquatic creatures created on day 5 would have had to have eaten before Adam's creation on 6, and they would have consumed other creatures, since the smallest creatures have to eat almost constantly to maintain enough energy to survive, killing them in the process.

So evidence from the Bible supports that death was part of creation from the beginning, both for other creatures, and for humans.

Comment: so it is a wrong notion when we say we die because of sin then.

Comment: If by "die", you mean physical death, then yes. On the other hand, in Romans 6:23, Paul juxtaposes "death" with "everlasting life", which I submit means that Paul intended to communicate that the wages of sin is death of the Soul, for certainly by the time Paul wrote Romans, there was already physical death.

Comment: Your first "fact" is an argument from silence, and a poor one. 1 Cor 15 indicates that even if the most serious death is spiritual, our hope is that we will be saved from physical death. "For as in Adam all die, so in Christ all will be made alive." I believe that in Adam we have holistic death and in Christ holistic life.

Comment: UnlessNo, the first argument is not an argument from silence.

Comment: Please disregard pervious comment. I started it before I realized I had to think more how to get what I wanted to say within the space allotment.